# Why database portability is given higher value than application portability

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, plsql, orm

We have ORM tools to like hibernate to abstract away the database, and typically all business logic resides in the application. This means we can change the database easily, but are locked to the application implementation.

Another way is to reside business logic in the database: stored procedures, functions and triggers. This means we are locked to the database, but could change application middleware easily.

Why is the former option more common? Typically one won't change the database anyway. In turn, stored procedures would reduce bandwidth load and are probably faster. Of course stored procedures are more difficult to maintain. What are other pros and cons of each solution?

Comment: There is a third hybrid option, which is that Hibernate can still call stored procedures.  I think that ORM tools are mainly to prevent the need from massive refactoring of app code just because the DB changes, and for performance as well.

Comment: Often developers think of a database as a "persistence" layer; somewhere for me to store my objects. And I can "get" and "set" these. And if I need to get a million of them, I call get a million times. The part that is often overlooked is that the database is also a processing engine. It is often cheaper and faster and more scalable to think of and use the database this way. http://thehelsinkideclaration.blogspot.com/2016/09/noplsql-vs-thickdb-which-one-requires.html

Comment: You might find the following questions in SoftwareEngineering [“Never do in code what you can get the SQL server to do well for you” - Is this a recipe for a bad design?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171024/34296) and [Is having functionality in DB a road block to scalability?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/166539/34296) interesting. IMO SE would be better place for your question than SO (I'm expecting the question to be closed soon).

Comment: Why do you think _"Of course stored procedures are more difficult to maintain."_ ?

Comment: @user272735 poor tools and obscure compiler messages. Java ecosystem is from a different league when it comes to rapid development and troubleshooting.

Comment: It's something I don't understand either. From my perspective it's like requiring to write a web-application independent of the web-framework because "it might change later". Writing DBMS independent SQL simply means that it's equally slow on all DBMS. Especially with commercial database it does not make any sense to me to **not** use all features I have paid for.

Comment: Stored procedures are not difficult to maintain. What a bizarre claim.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I agree 100%. The only thing I can think of is that it's more a case if what you know. If you only know Java, and don't know SQL, the of course stored procedures look hard :)